# Use typescript to extract type of type guard

Tags: typescript, generics, typeguards

I have the following function:

```
function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish {
  return (pet as Fish).swim !== undefined;
}
```

How can I extract the type `Fish` using `typeof isFish`?

---

For example:

```
type ExtractedFishType = GuardType<typeof isFish>
```

---

```
type GuardType<T> = ...
```

But how can i implement `GuardType`?

See this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgZwBZQLxQN4Cgq6ggdzgFsAuKAIwHsqAbCAQwDssBfLLUSKAITgCcAJmkw48AM1ohy1Ooxbss4gK5MAxsDhUmURPGQAKSMHL6UAH14DBASnLHdCWIhTZc-CMGX8dRz1AYnMxsAOkISKABCVHRVQQhxOCYIQQBuNg4uaABRAA9gfgYNFIAVcAgARhEAJU9vJjLIAB4sqnFHMwA+KAB6HqgPLx8nWXpmTPKoPIKi4FLygCYRAHFlBiFGiBbyto6Xbr78JCplWmEIfMKNKAAiMxuAGkplYChBKggnJipXgip+ADWWCAA) for reference.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXQnVN) work for you?  Note that this `GuardType<T>` only works if the function's *first* parameter is the guarded one.  If you don't know where the guarded parameter is (e.g., `(x: any, y: any) => y is Foo` or `(x: any, y: any, z: any) => z is Foo`, then this gets a lot tougher).  If it works for you I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes! Feel free to write up the answer:)

Comment: heh I see that this was closed as a duplicate of a question I've answered before.  oh well!